# JavaScript SlimScroll usage in Angular page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular, slimscroll

I am trying to use [SlimScroll](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll/) in an Angular page as shown below:

First I added the js file to `angular.json`:

```
"scripts": [
  "src/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "src/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
  "src/bower_components/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.js",
]
```

Then I try to call the related method in html as shown below:

```
<div class="example">
  
</div>
  

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $(".example").slimScroll({
      size: '4px', 
      width: '100%', 
      height: '100%', 
      color: '#ff4800', 
      allowPageScroll: true, 
      alwaysVisible: true     
    });
  });
</script>
```

But there is nothing on the page. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the slimscroll constructor code inside an ngOnInit. Whether it be for a specific `*.component.ts` or inside the `app.component.ts`.

```
ngOnInit(){
$(function(){
    $(".example").slimScroll({
      size: '4px', 
      width: '100%', 
      height: '100%', 
      color: '#ff4800', 
      allowPageScroll: true, 
      alwaysVisible: true     
    });
  });
}
```

The `ngOnInit` is invoked after the component's html is injected into the page.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it does not worked when adding `app.component.ts`. Instead of adding each component, how can I implement this definitions and configurations (in a .config file) for `slimscroll`? I use `core` and `shared` modules also, it would be ok for me or create a separate component for slimscroll part and then call it in the shared module so that I can easily use it in any component I want.

Comment: It would be perfect if I could define it as **directive**. Is that possible?

Comment: @Lorenzo If you are still including the slimscroll library in the `"scripts"` section of your `angular.json` file... then you just need to install the `@types/jquery.slimscroll` [reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery.slimscroll) in your `package.json`. This will resolve your typescript issue.

Comment: Which issue do you mean? I have just 2 issues in my last 2 comments. Could you please have a look at that?

Comment: Anyway, thanks a lot and voted up for your helps.